# Mapa lento ao pressionar o botão de voltar

Tags: android, google-maps

Em uma aplicação que o Fragmento inicial é o SupportMapFragment, quando eu troco de fragment e acabo apertando o botão de voltar ele retorna para o fragmento do mapa, fica muito lento a movimentação do mesmo.
Alguém sabe o que ocorre?

Comment: Isso costuma acontecer quando o app está rodando em modo debug. Tente rodar fora do debugger e veja se a performance melhora.

Comment: Não estou rodando em modo debug não..

Comment: Acredito que tenha haver por eu estar voltando a um fragment que já existe e aí no oncreateview ele faz todo processo de inflar o mapa etc.